# Plotting numbers of different colors

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with the next structure:

```
  x    |      y     |  color     |   type  | count 
___________________ _______________________________  
 0     |     1    |   black      | type1   |  4
 0     |     2    |   black      | type2   |  3
 0     |     3    |   red        | type3   |  7
 0     |     4    |  yellow      | type4   |  4
 1     |     1    |  green       | type5   |  8
______________________________________________________
```

and I want to plot the numbers in their x,y corrdinate with their correspoding color in a scatterplot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=120)
ax = f.add_subplot(111)

for i in range(len(data_graph)):
    x = data_graph.loc[i,'x']
    y = data_graph.loc[i,'y']
    c = str(data_graph.loc[i,'color'])
    print(c)
    t = str(data_graph.loc[i,'count'])
    ax.text(x,y,t, ha="center", va="center",color=c)
    ax.scatter(x,y, alpha=0)

plt.show()
```

If i specify a single color the numbers appear correctly, but when i try to assign the color to each text it shows only the black and doesn't show the res, what am I doing wrong?

I also want to add a legend with the color and the type

[image: Something like this, but with the numbers in different colors]
Something like this, but with the numbers in different colors

Comment: Surprisingly the code you provide shows for me the expected result...

Comment: omg I had written a color wrong and for some reason there was no error message haha

Comment: By the way, I suggest removing ax.scatter(x,y, alpha=0)` and using instead `plt.xlim(data_graph.x.min()-0.5, data_graph.x.max()+0.5)` and `plt.ylim(...)` before `plt.show()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0,0,0,0,1]) # x = data_graph.x.values
y = np.array([1,2,3,4,1]) # y = data_graph.y.values
color = np.array(['black', 'black', 'red', 'yellow', 'green']) # color = data_graph.color.values
types = np.array(['type1','type2','type3','type4','type5']) # types = data_graph.type.values

for i in range(np.unique(color).shape[0]):
    x_plot = x[color== np.unique(color)[i]]
    y_plot = y[color== np.unique(color)[i]]
    c = np.unique(color)[i]
    label = np.unique(color)[i] +'_' + types[i]
    plt.scatter(x_plot,y_plot, c = c, label=label)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Or depending on what you need:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0,0,0,0,1]) # x = data_graph.x.values
y = np.array([1,2,3,4,1]) # y = data_graph.y.values
color = np.array(['black', 'black', 'red', 'yellow', 'green']) # color = data_graph.color.values
types = np.array(['type1','type2','type3','type4','type5'])

for i in range(np.unique(types).shape[0]):
    x_plot = x[types== np.unique(types)[i]]
    y_plot = y[types== np.unique(types)[i]]
    c = color[types==types[i]][0]
    label = c +'_' + types[i]
    plt.scatter(x_plot,y_plot, c = c, label=label)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Or depending on what you need:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0,0,0,0,1]) # x = data_graph.x.values
y = np.array([1,2,3,4,1]) # y = data_graph.y.values
color = np.array(['black', 'black', 'red', 'yellow', 'green']) # color = data_graph.color.values
types = np.array(['type1','type2','type3','type4','type5'])

texts = np.array([20,30,40,50,60])

for i in range(np.unique(types).shape[0]):
    x_plot = x[types== np.unique(types)[i]]
    y_plot = y[types== np.unique(types)[i]]
    c = color[types==types[i]][0]
    label = c +'_' + types[i]
    plt.scatter(x_plot,y_plot, c = c, label=label)

for i, txt in enumerate(texts):
    plt.annotate(txt, (x[i], y[i]))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Specifically for his problem: `plt.scatter(data_graph.x, data_graph.y, c=data_graph.color)`

Comment: But that would just plot the points right? What would I do if i wanted text instead of the point?

Comment: see the last part of my answer. consider upvoting and accepting my anaswer. I covered all 3 possible cases